# How to access "Allow users to edit ranges" option in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there way to access `Allow Users To Edit Ranges` Option in Excel under `Review` tab > `Changes` group > `Allow Users To Edit Ranges` through VBA. I want to add password to certain cells in excel worksheet through VBA.

Comment: Try recording a macro while doing so and see how it's captured.

Comment: Wow sir, You have given me a permanent solution to these type of problems to access the different options. Your idea worked. Salute !!!

Comment: Glad it helped and thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @ Máté Juhász idea, I found the option in VBA by recording the macro and looking into that macro code.

```
    Range("D9:I18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Range1", Range:=Range( _
    "D9:I18"), Password:="123"
```